# Not sure how to return an arry of objects where each object has an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a database full of guitar objects. I also have a service record that has a many to 1 relationship with the guitars: guitar can have many service records but a service record can only have one guitar.

I am trying to return a JSON list that has this kind of format:

```
guitar [{
    "guitarId":1,
    "guitarMake":"Fender",
    "guitarModel":"Telecaster",
    "serviceRecords" : [{
        "serviceRecordId":1,
    },
    {
        "serviceRecordId":2,
    }];
}]
```

What would be the most efficient way to create this function on my express server so I get an object returned like this? Should I go the GraphQL route, or should make two function calls in order to construct this list and return?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Pavindu I;m using a MySQL databse

Comment: Have a look at [Sequlize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) and see if that fits your needs.